# SQL error when trying to delete a row from my table

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, sql-delete

I have an issue and get this SQL error that I can't identify the source of. It's blocking the delete API and nothing is clear about it on the internet:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_re". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.MatchingTable", column 'M_Id'.
>
> The statement has been terminated. The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_re". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.MatchingTable", column 'M_Id'.

Comment: You have to truncate or delete the records from the parent table of the foriegn key before it can be removed from the child table.

Comment: It's just vice versa. Let'ssay there are two tables, student and student_phone, because one student can have several phone numbers. Usually the student_phone table would have a foreign key to the student table. If you try to delete a student row, but there still is a student_table row on that student, then you'll get this error. You would have to delete the student's student_phone rows first, before you can delete the student row. So it's delete from the child table first, and only then can you delete from the parent table.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL requests should always be tagged with the DBMS. Once we know the DBMS we may be able to tell you how to find out which child table is being referenced by FK_re.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thank you. I am not good at explaining the situation, as I am versed in correcting it when I run into it on testing databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_re"

this means you can't delete what you want to because there is a foreign key  reference.

The tables are linked by a piece of data in certain column, and SQL is warning you that if you do that the link will be to nothing.

This is one of the strengths of SQL data integrity.